# ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript NOT working on server

Tags: asp.net, registerstartupscript

I'm having troubles with the following piece of code. It works really good in my local machine, but when I deploy it in the dev server it doesn't work at all. I've searched in a lot of places for a solution but with not successfully.

I have a gridview in which one column is a buttonfield. This button field opens a popup displaying the detail of the selected sales order.

In order to show the popup I use the following sentence:

```
    private void OpenPopup(string name_)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(home), "Popup", string.Concat("<script type='text/javascript'>OpenPopup('", name_, "');</script>"));
    }
```

The OpenPopup() is a javascript function which simply displays the popup (I've tested it and it works fine, so I wont show unnecessary code):

When RegisterStartupScript is executed in my local enviroment it works fine and the result in the page source is the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>OpenPopup('items');</script>
```

Now, when I publish the site and deploy it in the server it doesn't work at all. I've already tried to make it work using **Scriptmanager**, but with the same result; it works locally but not in the server.

The added script isn't being written at all.

I really apretiate any kind of help. I've already searched a lot with lots of approaches but no solution for me...

Thanks a lot.

/Edit: I do not use updatepanel in the page.

Comment: Can you verify the the OpenPopup() server method is ever called?

Comment: Also, is this the only thing that happens when you click the button (ie, would this better if we made the button open the popup without ever posting to the server)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using .RegisterClientScriptBlock? This is what I always use in order to call the JS in the codebehind.

Could you try something like the code below?

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Boolean dne = false;
    StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
    String scriptName = "";



    if (AdminAccess.DoesUserExist(txtUsername.Text))
    {
        errorMessage.Append("alert('The selected username " + txtUsername.Text + " is already in use.  Please choose another. ');");
        scriptName = "duplicateUsername";
        if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(scriptName))
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), scriptName, errorMessage.ToString(), true);
        }
        dne = true;
    }
```

}

Comment: Hello. This doesn't work because RegisterClientScriptBlock makes the javascript call to be executed before the other controls are created. RegisterStartupScript place the call at the bottom of the code, which is correct and works fine on my local enviroment. I really dont know why this is happening. I think it has to be something that differs in the server, in comparison with my local enviroment.

Comment: What other controls are you creating inside the event handler?

Comment: I'm using a gridview which is hidden and populated before this call. After the gridview is populated, I'm trying to call this function in order to popup this gridview.

Comment: If the gridview is already populated is simply hidden, then wouldn't registerclientscriptblock work in this situation. The only reason I say this is because you are programmatically controlling when it executes so the rest of your page can load before you allow it to be executed.